# Private members of the interface

Tags: c#

If in my program I have the interface, then all it's members are **public** implicitly. And in the class, which implements that interface, I must make that members (properties) **public** too.

Is it any way to make it **private**?

Comment: [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) discusses it in terms of when you *have* to use it, but it's actually always possible.

Comment: No, the point of an interface is to define the publicly available behavior of a class that implements it...the private methods shouldn't matter to the consumer of the interface.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the interface methods you do not want a specific class to implement?

Comment: @SamusArin I want to access the properties of the interface had only one class that implements this interface

Comment: I would need to see more code, not too sure what your goal is...

Comment: Thanks, but I already got the answer to my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it any way to make an interface implementation private?

Not *completely* private - an interface represents a *public set of methods and properties*.  There is no way to make interface implementations private.

What you *can* do is make the implementation *explicit*:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   void Bar();
}

public class FooImpl
{
    void IFoo.Bar()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("I am somewhat private.")
    }

    private void Bar()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("I am private.")
    }

}
```

Now the only way to call `IFoo.Bar()` is *explicitly* through the interface:

```
FooImpl f = new FooImpl();
f.Bar();   // compiler error
((IFoo)f).Bar();
```

Comment: And, if the intent is to prevent clients outside of your assembly from accessing those members, making the interface internal in addition to implementing it explicitly will do the trick.

Comment: On the one hand, this is a great technical answer to the question asked. On the other, answers like this always feel a bit irresponsible when they don't make any mention at all of why this is almost certainly a bad thing to do.

Comment: @DStanley Well I don't like answers that just say why it's bad without giving a real answer to the question either! I think between the answers and comments this is probably just about covered to a reasonable level of depth anyway

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

The basic idea of an interface is that its a contract between your classes and components, so that means its members are intended for public use. If you need your members private that probably means you might want to revisit your design.

Comment: ... like breaking apart the interface into sub-interfaces, possibly creating inheritance hierarchies of them and such.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces are meant to be exposed publicly.

What you can do though is switch to an abstract base class with protected abstract members. In many ways this will achieve the same end by forcing implementers to have the method without it being public.

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    protected abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

The main con to this is that you don't get multiple inheritance with abstract classes like you do with interfaces, so weigh how important this need is to you.