# Set interface us a properties c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

I've created three interfaces - IUser, ICostCenter, IDepartment. IUser and IDepartment are properties of ICostCenter.

```
public interface ICostCenter
{
    IDepartment Department { get; set; }
    User.IUser CostCenterHead { get; set; }
}
```

The class implementing ICostCenter will be used in the DbContext for my db.

```
public class tblCostCenter : WorkingInterface.Interface.Organization.ICostCenter
{
    public tblCostCenter()
    {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    private WorkingInterface.Interface.User.IUser CostCenterHead { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public Model.tblUser UserObject
    {
        get { return (Model.tblUser)this.CostCenterHead; }
        set { this.CostCenterHead = value; }
    }

    private WorkingInterface.Interface.Organization.IDepartment Department { get; set; }
    public string DepartmenID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmenID")]
    public Model.tblDepartment DepartmentObject
    {
        get { return (Model.tblDepartment)this.Department; }
        set { this.Department = (Model.tblDepartment)value; }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error because I made the IUser and IDepartment properties private. How can I properly implement the interface? I want these properties to be hidden.

Comment: make it public,   you have explicitly said it implements the ICostCenter, which means it must have a public Departmen and usert, you aren't allowed to make it private.  It breaks the interface

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to clarify what you wanted to achieve? Clearly you know that methods/properties that implement an interface should be either public of follow explicit interface implementation syntax... so what exactly you want to achieve with making them private?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private members of the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545232/private-members-of-the-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is declared explicitly as `public`, that means that all the members declared in that interface *MUST* be `public`

So you need to declare both of these properties as public:

public WorkingInterface.Interface.User.IUser CostCenterHead { get; set; }
public WorkingInterface.Interface.Organization.IDepartment Department { get; set; }

> NOTE: these have been declared as *implicit* implementations, so they are available to all contexts. If you want to hide them from general use, you can use *explicit* implementation.

Because you tried to use `private` accessibility, I assume you generally want to hide these properties from view, you can do this and still honor the interface contract by using *explicit* implementation syntax:

WorkingInterface.Interface.User.IUser ICostCenter.CostCenterHead { get; set; }
WorkingInterface.Interface.Organization.IDepartment ICostCenter.Department { get; set; }

They are still `public` but can only be accessed by first casting the object to the specific interface type *explicitly*.

```
tblCostCenter obj = new tblCostCenter();
...
// this wont work:
Console.WriteLine(obj.CostCenterHead);
// instead you will have to cast the object first
Console.WriteLine((obj as ICostCenter)).CostCenterHead);
// or if the local variable was an ICostCenter
ICostCenter costObj = obj;
Console.WriteLine(costObj.CostCenterHead);
...
// Pattern matching can also be helpful in these scenarios
if (obj is ICostCenter cc)
     Console.WriteLine(cc.CostCenterHead);
```

If you want to use explicit declaration in your class you could try this:

```
WorkingInterface.Interface.User.IUser ICostCenter.CostCenterHead { get; set; }
public string UserID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserID")]
public Model.tblUser UserObject
{
    get { return ((ICostCenter)this).CostCenterHead as Model.tblUser; }
    set { ((ICostCenter)this).CostCenterHead = value; }
}

WorkingInterface.Interface.Organization.IDepartment ICostCenter.Department { get; set; }
public string DepartmenID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DepartmenID")]
public Model.tblDepartment DepartmentObject
{
    get { return ((ICostCenter)this).Department as Model.tblDepartment; }
    set { ((ICostCenter)this).Department = value; }
}
```

> this only works if:
>
> - Model.tblDepartment : IDepartment
> - Model.tblUser : User.IUser

Comment: Thanks but my problem now is Im not able to access the interface in the `public Model.tblUser UserObject
    {
        get { return (Model.tblUser)this.CostCenterHead; }
        set { this.CostCenterHead = value; }
    }`

Comment: Did you go with Implicit or Explicit declaration? I'll update my post with more of an Explicit implementation